# estimate AIC/BIC criteria from given signal

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, autoregressive-models

suppose  we  following model

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15326/can-someone-show-the-details-of-how-to-apply-aic-for-sinusoidal-models-to-specif

where   epsilon is white noise,i have tried following  code

```
function [aic_matrix,bic_matrix]=ARMA_model(y,n);
%n possible order of each model
LOGL = zeros(n,n); %Initialize
PQ = zeros(n,n);
for p = 1:n
    for q = 1:n
        mod = arima(p,0,p);
        [fit,~,logL] = estimate(mod,y,'print',false);
        LOGL(p,q) = logL;
        PQ(p,q) = p+q;
     end
end
LOGL = reshape(LOGL,n*n,1);
PQ = reshape(PQ,n*n,1);
[aic1,bic1] = aicbic(LOGL,PQ+1,length(y));
aic_matrix=reshape(aic1,n,n);
bic_matrix=reshape(bic1,n,n);
end
```

but when i ran following command

```
[aic_matric,bic_matrix]=ARMA_model(B,100);
```

i got result

```
Error using arima/validateModel (line 1314)
The non-seasonal moving average polynomial is non-invertible.

Error in arima/setLagOp (line 391)
   Mdl = validateModel(Mdl);

Error in arima/estimate (line 1183)
  Mdl = setLagOp(Mdl, 'MA' , LagOp([1  coefficients(iMA)' ], 'Lags', [0 LagsMA ]));

Error in ARMA_model (line 9)
        [fit,~,logL] = estimate(mod,y,'print',false);
```

does it means that  this signal is non stationary?what is  a problem related to my  code?please help me

Comment: I think this line is incorrect: `mod = arima(p,0,p);` I think it should be `mod = arima(p,0,q);`.  Also, you really don't want the MA part of the system to have a higher order than the AR part (which is what your loop would do if the error was fixed).  The loop `for q = 1:n` should read `for q = 1:p`.

Comment: and  what is more  stable ,AIC or BIC?

Comment: can i  write it as  arima(p,0,0)?

Comment: Yes, that will just give you an AR model (which is probably OK for the sinusoidal model case).  Please don't use comments for chat. Please go here for chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing

Comment: but how advice is given in this case?is AR model good for sinusoidal models?also  because it is  in noise,there is always advice to take high AR order,but how high?let us suppose that i have these two matrix,and let us suppose that i have given possible order 80,is this good size?

Comment: so finally how can i change my code?

Comment: Please go here for chat: chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is incorrect:

```
mod = arima(p,0,p);
```

I think it should be

```
mod = arima(p,0,q);
```

Also, you really don't want the MA part of the system to have a higher order than the AR part (which is what your loop would do if the error was fixed). The loop

```
for q = 1:n
```

should read

```
for q = 1:p.
```

Your code seems OK, apart from those issues.

Comment: but for huge number of P,there is mistake,time out

Comment: The timeout is probably due to the data not being able to cope with an order of 100. That's VERY large for an ARIMA model.